# Registering Servicestack custom auth provider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, mono, servicestack

I'm having a bit of trouble registering custom authentication providers in Servicestack. I'm using the following to configure authentication for my service:

```
        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(),
                new IAuthProvider[] { 
                    new VendorAuth(appSettings),
                    new FacilitiesAuth(appSettings)
                }, null));
```

As a test, the first auth provider is simply setup to always succeed:

```
    public class VendorAuth : CredentialsAuthProvider
    {

        public VendorAuth(AppSettings appSettings) : base(appSettings) { } 

        public override object Authenticate(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, Auth request)
        {
            return base.Authenticate(authService, session, request);
        }

        public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
        {
            return true; 
        }
    }
```

This is where my understanding may be falling apart a bit. But in the client, I am trying to get to the "VendorAuth" provider in this manner:

```
    public class VendorAuth : Auth
    {
    }
```

```
    var AuthResponse = client.Post(new VendorAuth
    {
        provider = "credentials", // This may be an issue
        UserName = "someuser", 
        Password = "somepass",
        RememberMe = true
    });
```

This always seems to return a 405 when the client attempts to authenticate:

```
POST /json/syncreply/VendorAuth HTTP/1.1" 405
```

So I guess the question is... Does it appear as if I am registering my custom auth providers correctly?

Comment: which is the url you are trying to do the post?

Comment: try to change the  VendorAuth : Auth with another name, maybe that´s causing you some conflicts with auth provider.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the following:

```
public override bool IsAuthorized(IAuthSession session, IAuthTokens tokens, Authenticate request = null)
{
    return true;
}
```

This is likely the call that is failing.  If it now works, replace the `return true` with a call to the base implementation and debug through it to find the code that's causing the failure.